# Not all tangents to a plane curve are bitangents

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves

I'm struggling on a question from a previous qualifying exam, and I don't see a clean way to do it.

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a connected, 1-dimensional, real analytic submanifold, not contained in a line. Why does there exist a tangent line to $X$ that not bitangent (tangent to $X$ at more than one point)?

Out of curiosity, is the statement still true if we drop the condition that $X$ is real analytic (so just smooth)?

Comment: would a spiral form a submanifold in your definition ? Certainly a spiral has no tangent line which just touches the spiral at the point of tangency alone.

Comment: But in order to be bitangent, it has to be tangent at other points, not just intersect the curve, so I don't think it would be a counterexample? But yeah, I don't have enough of an idea of what "analytic" means to tell you if a spiral is real analytic.

Comment: I guess, $\sin$ and $\cos$ are analytic functions and apparently there is an inverse function theorem for real analytic functions after a google search, so it's an analytic submanifold.

Comment: Ah, right, so for the graph of sine or cosine it's easy enough to see tangents which are not bitangent. For example, $y=\sin x$ has $y=x$ as a tangent which is not a bitangent. In fact, I think it's almost always the case that tangents to sine and cosine are not bitangent with the exception of $y=\pm 1$ which are the common tangents to the extremal points of the graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first instinct was to approach this in terms of analytic curves (say, in the projective plane) and their dual curves. But this is total overkill. It should just be an elementary exercise in the differential geometry of curves, if we make some reasonable assumptions. When $X$ is contained in a line, its curvature $\kappa$ is identically $0$. Real analyticity of $X$ and the assumption that $X$ is not contained in a line will tell you that the zeroes of $\kappa$ must be isolated, and then the proof will work. (I leave it to you to ponder what happens if you just assume $X$ is $C^2$. How horrendous can the $0$-set of the curvature be then?)

It is really a local exercise, proceeding by contradiction. Assume that we arclength parametrize $X$ by $\alpha(s)$ and let $\beta(s)$ be the (locally, a?) "companion point" so that the tangent lines of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ agree. Write $\beta(s) = \alpha(s)+\lambda(s)T(s)$, where $T(s)$ is the unit tangent vector at $\alpha(s)$. Assuming $\lambda$ is differentiable (away from trouble points this should follow from the implicit function theorem), we have
$$\beta'(s) = \alpha'(s) + \lambda'(s)T(s) + \lambda(s)\kappa(s)N(s),$$
where $T(s),N(s)$ give a smoothly-varying orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^2$. The fact that $\beta'(s)$ is a scalar multiple of $\alpha'(s)=T(s)$ tells us that $\lambda(s)\kappa(s)=0$ for all $s$. So, away from zeroes of $\kappa$ we must have $\lambda = 0$, which means there is no bitangent companion point at all.

**EDIT**: @JohnHughes's point is well taken. Since this situation cannot occur (bitangencies occur generically only in isolated situations), it is very difficult to have good intuition. Here is a direct approach, again assuming real analyticity to get only isolated zeroes for $\kappa$. Because we want to work with the tangent lines as *affine* lines, and not as subspaces, it is most natural to work projectively. I can translate the notation I use if necessary.

Given the curve $\alpha\colon I\to\Bbb R^2$ (for an appropriate interval $I$), again assumed to be arclength-parametrized, we consider $f\colon I\to \Bbb R^3$, with $f(s) = (\alpha(s),1)$. To say that $\alpha(t)$ lies on the tangent line at $\alpha(s)$ is to say that $f(s)\wedge f'(s)\wedge f(t) = 0$ (i.e., the three vectors $f(s),f'(s),f(t)$ are linearly dependent). Symmetrically, to say that $\alpha(s)$ lies on the tangent line at $\alpha(t)$ is to say that $f(t)\wedge f'(t)\wedge f(s) = 0$.  So we're interested in pairs $(s,t)$ with $s\ne t$ and $$F(s,t) = \big(f(s)\wedge f'(s)\wedge f(t),f(t)\wedge f'(t)\wedge f(s)\big) = (0,0).$$
(To be a bit more careful, throughout we must choose an identification $\Lambda^3(\Bbb R^3) \cong \Bbb R$. To be concrete, let's set $T(s)\wedge N(s)\wedge (0,0,1)$ equal to $1$.) Now, we just calculate:
$$DF(s,t) = \begin{bmatrix} f(s)\wedge f''(s)\wedge f(t) & f(s)\wedge f'(s)\wedge f'(t) \\ f(t)\wedge f'(t)\wedge f'(s) & f(t)\wedge f''(t)\wedge f(s)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\lambda(s,t)\kappa(t) & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda(s,t)\kappa(s)\end{bmatrix},$$
where, at a point $(s,t)$ with $F(s,t)=(0,0)$, we write $\alpha(t) = \alpha(s)+\lambda(s,t)T(s)$. Note that $\alpha(s)\ne\alpha(t)$ tells us that $\lambda(s,t)\ne 0$. So, so long as $\kappa(s)$ and $\kappa(t)$ are both nonzero, $DF(s,t)$ will be nonsingular, which means that — away from zeroes of curvature — $F^{-1}(0,0)$ consists of isolated points, as required.

Comment: I have doubts about this line of reasoning: you assume that the "companion" point is a smooth function of the parameter $s$, but I don't see why this is a valid assumption. (Indeed, if the curvature at the first point $P$ is nonzero, and the companion point to $P$ is $Q$, then the tangent vectors to tangent lines near $P$ define a kind of vector field near $Q$, albeit a "multi-valued" one, and I think that in general this "vector field" admits no integral curves, showing that the notion of "smoothly varying companion" doesn't really make sense.  But I'm probably missing something. :(

Comment: I think this makes sense. To check my understanding, do we have minor typos $\Lambda^3\mathbb{R}^3\cong \mathbb{R}$ and the top left entry of the matrix is $f(s)\wedge f''(s)\wedge f(t)$? Also, at the end, can we also say $f''(s)$ is normal to the curve, so not on the line connecting $f(s)$ and $f(t)$, so $f(s)\wedge f''(s)\wedge f(t)\neq 0$, as long as $f''(s)\neq 0$? Finally, just as a curiosity, you mentioned real analytic curves in the projective plane and their duals. How different is this from plane curves in algebraic geometry?

Comment: Thanks for catching the typos; I switched notation from what I'd scribbled on my piece of paper. The theory of real analytic plane curves shouldn't be any different from the (local) theory of algebraic curves. If you look at classic treatments, they work with power series and (in the singular case) Puiseux series locally a lot.

Comment: Nicely repaired, Ted! The new answer is far more satisfying. I keep thinking that there has to be an easier way, as this seems pretty tough for a quals question. It seems as if something like the Fabricius-Bjerre theorem (https://vimeo.com/60888443) ought to help...except that it requires that the curve be "generic". Sigh.